# Show custom url?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

How to display custom url and not based on controller and action names?

My routing looks like

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "productfeature",
        url: "cn/pendrive/18-gb",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Feature", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}
```

and my link button looks like

```
<li>@Html.RouteLink("Product Feature", "productfeature")</li>
```

I get url as the Url mentioned in the code but i also 404 error.

```
http://localhost:9090/cn/pendrive/18-gb
```

How to go for static urls? Basically my aim is to no show controllers and action names in url.

Comment: MVC will check each route from top to bottom and pick the first on it matches. Having the default at the top means it will ignore all your other routes, and in this case tries to find a `pendrive` action in a `cn` controller and pass a parameter with value `'18-gb'`, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Moved the default one to bottom and works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your custom route before the default one:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "productfeature",
    url: "cn/pendrive/18-gb",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Feature", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now works correctly. Working on First MVC application. :-)